# Positioning Sub Nav Menu Underneath Main Nav

Tags: css, css-animations, z-index

I'm using CSS transition to do a dropdown menu. The animation itself works however I'm having issues with the sub nav appearing on top of the main nav.

I tried adding a high z-index on the main menu link, but this doesn't work:

```
.navUl li a {
  z-index:9999;
}
```

Subnav code:

```
.navUl li ul {
  background-color: green;
  width: 264px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
```

So how do I get the sub nav sliding down underneath the main nav?

Here's the [link for reference](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvadVag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index : -1` to Subnav :

```
.navUl li ul {
  background-color: green;
  width: 264px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Don´t need to add `z-index:9999;` to `.navUl li a`